# Problems with Pyramid Traversal and Browsers Back-Button

Tags: ajax, web, pyramid, traversal

I'm using Pyramids Traversal and got some problems. Let us say, I've this config:

```
config.add_route('main_dis','/dis/{params}/go')
config.add_route('ajax_R1', '/dis/{url:.*}ajax_R1')
config.add_route('ajax_R2', '/dis/{url:.*}ajax_R2')
```

whereby the first one is a view config for chameleon, and the second and third one for json. If I call www.example.com/dis/A/go, an ajax request will get information by calling ajax_R1. Afterwards the user can click something and go to www.example.com/dis/B/go, which calls ajax_R2. If the user want to navigate back from B towards A, the ajax request is fired, but pyramids does not finds the suitable view, so that the notfound_view_config is called. Does someone has an idea for this behaviour?

One "dirty fix" is to check the path-variable in the request of the notfound_view_config and calling the suitable method, but this is very dirty :(

Thanks,
Tobias

P.S.: Hopefully my problem will not be taken the wrong way :)

Comment: There is not enough information here to understand what you are asking. If the request works when navigating to page A, then even if the user uses the back button it should continue to work since the user is once again navigating to A. What URL is your browser sending when the user clicks the back button back to A?

Comment: The browser send the right url, but pyramids says, that he did not find the suitable view. Currently, i lookup the url paramter in the notfound_view_config for redirecting while having this missbehaviour.

Comment: Just a note on terminology you are not using pyramid traversal in your config above, you are defining routes .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ViewNotFound while Ajax and Pyramids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617880/viewnotfound-while-ajax-and-pyramids)