# ViewNotFound while Ajax and Pyramids

Tags: ajax, transactions, pyramid, traversal

I'm using Pyramid and got a strange issue. I do an ajax request AR in view A. If the request is done, the user is redirected to view B. If the user goes back to A, the ajax request AR will fail, because pyramid does not find any view for the request.

If someone needs code, I'll post it ;-)

Thx & Greetings
Tobias

Edit:

Snippet of my **init**.py

```
# adding all routes
config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
config.add_route('main_page',               '/')
config.add_route('main_contact',            '/contact')
config.add_route('main_discussion_start',   '/discussion/start')
config.add_route('main_discussion_issue',   '/discussion/start/issue={issue}')
config.add_route('main_discussion',         '/discussion/{parameters}/{service}/go')
config.add_route('main_settings',           '/settings')
config.add_route('main_news',               '/news')
config.add_route('main_imprint',            '/imprint')
config.add_route('404',                     '/404')

# ajax for navigation logic, administraion, settigs and editing/viewing log
config.add_route('ajax_get_start_statements',                '/discussion/{url:.*}ajax_get_start_statements')
config.add_route('ajax_get_premisses_for_statement',         '/discussion/{url:.*}ajax_get_premisses_for_statement')
config.add_route('ajax_reply_for_premissegroup',             '/discussion/{url:.*}ajax_reply_for_premissegroup')

config.add_route('ajax_user_login',                          '{url:.*}ajax_user_login')
config.add_route('ajax_user_logout',                         '{url:.*}ajax_user_logout')

config.add_route('ajax_set_new_start_statement',             '/discussion/{url:.*}ajax_set_new_start_statement{params:.*}')
config.add_route('ajax_set_new_start_premisse',              '/discussion/{url:.*}ajax_set_new_start_premisse{params:.*}')
config.add_route('ajax_set_new_premisses_for_X',             '/discussion/{url:.*}ajax_set_new_premisses_for_X{params:.*}')
config.add_route('ajax_set_correcture_of_statement',         '/discussion/{url:.*}ajax_set_correcture_of_statement{params:.*}')

config.add_route('ajax_user_registration',                   '{url:.*}ajax_user_registration')
config.add_route('ajax_user_password_request',               '{url:.*}ajax_user_password_request')
config.add_route('ajax_fuzzy_search',                        '{url:.*}ajax_fuzzy_search')
config.add_route('ajax_get_issue_list',                      '{url:.*}ajax_get_issue_list')
config.add_route('ajax_switch_language',                     '{url:.*}ajax_switch_language{params:.*}')
```

Head out of view not found in view.py

```
# 404 page
@notfound_view_config(renderer='templates/404.pt')
def notfound(self):
    """
    View configuration for the 404 page.
    :return: dictionary with title and project name as well as a value, weather the user is logged in
    """
    logger('- - - - - - - - - - - -', '- - - - - - - - - - - -', '- - - - - - - - - - - -')
    logger('notfound', 'def', 'main in ' + str(self.request.method) + '-request')
....
```

And one example ajax-call

```
/**
 * TODO: some text
 * @param statement for sending
 * @param issue for sending
 */
this.sendNewStartStatement = function (statement, issue) {
    var csrfToken = $('#' + hiddenCSRFTokenId).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_set_new_start_statement',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            statement: statement, issue: issue
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
        }
    }).done(function ajaxSendStartStatementDone(data) {
        new InteractionHandler().callbackIfDoneForSendNewStartStatement(data);
    }).fail(function ajaxSendStartStatementFail() {
        alert('fail in ajax 4');
        // canceled while debuging
    });
};
```

Comment: Can this error be based on my CSRF checks? I'm calling get_new_csrf_token() in every view instead of calling get_csrf_token().

Comment: It is hard to understand here what is wrong. Can you please try to narrow down the question to a repeatable example, so the readers can reproduce the problem themselves.

Comment: Problem: An ajax request will be done successfully on view A, afterwards the user will be directed do view B. If the user navigates back to A, the same ajax request will fail.

Comment: Yes I can read the what you are saying, but there is no way for me to repeat this on my own laptop it and I do not have full access to source, so it is pretty hard to say anything besides guessing.

Comment: You need to narrow down the problem to **minimal repeatable example**.

Comment: How to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If  would breakdown my problem into an minimal example, the error is not repeatable. Not everything can be done easy. Nevertheless, the problem was solved with the change given in my first comment :-)

Comment: We would have to see your `view_config` statements as well to get a better idea as to what is going on, but most likely the CSRF token the AJAX call is using is no longer valid, the CSRF predicate then won't allow the view to match, and thus you get a 404.

Comment: I have two kinds of statements. The first one renders chameleon like:
    @view_config(route_name='main_news', renderer='templates/news.pt', permission='everybody')
And the second one is for json data (ajax request):
    @view_config(route_name='ajax_reply_for_premisegroup', renderer='json', check_csrf=False)
The problem was, that every html view created a new csrf token instead of using the one out of the session :)